# how to install docker-ce 17+ on centos 6.9?

Tags: centos, centos6, docker, installation

Im currently trying to install docker-ce 17+ on a centOS 6.9 server, however, when running yum install docker-ce i get the following errors:

```
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
          Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
```

If i run it with the skip broken flag i get still the same message,

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?  Same issue exists still. Pegging version doesn't help me

Comment: Not really, although amazon linux is based on a centOS version lower than 7 and it can run docker-ce without issues, i suspect they might have recompiled a bunch of stuff and requirements for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to peg the version:

```
$ yum install --setopt=obsoletes=0 \
   docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 \
   docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch # on a new system with yum repo defined, forcing older version and ignoring obsoletes introduced by 17.06.0
```

More details here:
https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/20

Comment: Not working for me, unfortunately. Maybe because kernel version less then 3.x.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me, Centos 6.9 - how can installing an EL7 on an EL6 host (as above) work?

Comment: Not for me either. CentOS 6.7

Comment: .el7 means Centos7 onwards